# Showing of JavaFX Scene randomly delayed

Tags: javafx, show, scene, stage, borderpane

I have created a JavaFX application (running on Ubuntu, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)) and have made a simple test application:

```
  public class DelayedSceneApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        // Root.
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // Buttons box.
        HBox buttonBox = new HBox();
        buttonBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(new Button("Test"));

        root.setBottom(buttonBox);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
  }
```

The problem is that sometimes, after the stage has been shown, the scene is not loaded. Sometimes it takes one second to show the button, sometimes more then 20 seconds. When the scene has not been shown yet and clicking on the scene, the button shows immediately. Again, sometimes the button shows correctly at start up. This happens, as mentioned randomly. To reproduce this behavior one has to restart the application multiple times. Where did I make a mistake? Is it bug? Is it maybe not reproducible in an other environment (Windows, other JAVA Version, ...)?

Thank you very much!

**Update:** 
The output with `-Dprism.verbose=true` option:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 16384
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 16384
Maximum number of varying components = 128
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 32
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 32
Graphics Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
       Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2 
        Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
 vsync: true vpipe: true
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillPgram_Color.frag
new alphas
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_LinearGradient_PAD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureFirstPassLCD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureSecondPassLCD.frag
```

Comment: This sounds like a graphics-related issue. Could you include the output of running your program with `-Dprism.verbose=true`? You may also want to try upgrading graphics drivers, or disabling hardware acceleration with `-Dprism.order=sw` to see if it helps.

Comment: @sillyfly Thank you very much, that solved it. However, I wrecked my OS when updating the graphic card driver, therefore the late reply, but that's an other issue. This problem only occurs so far with JavaFX, I have not seen other applications having the same problem. Thus I wonder why only JavaFX has this problem? Should I include `-Dprism.order=sw`as standard option when packaging the application in order to guarantee, that it works everywhere? Or is this discouraged?. You can post your comment as answer  to this question, after that I can mark it as the correct one. Thank you again!

Comment: `-Dprism.order=sw` completely disables hardware acceleration, so performance will suffer - it is a workaround at best, but should probably only be used for diagnostics. In my opinion, it is not at all a good idea to include it as a default release option. You should try to find the underlying cause so you can really solve it - however, I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Including the output when running with `-Dprism.verbose=true` (but without `order=sw`) may provide additional hints.

Comment: @sillyfly I updated the question with the ouput when running `-Dprism.verbose=true`

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, but I'm not an expert. Does this output change in any way when the erroneous behavior occurs, compared to a normal run? Also, since you're on Linux, are you using the KMS Intel driver? Sometimes using the KMS vs non-KMS (or vice versa) can solve some problems.

Comment: @sillyfly There is no difference between the output. I will try it at some other time with an other environment. Currently I am using the nvidia-384 driver with the intel option, previously I used the nouveau standard driver. Both show the same behavior. However, it definitely  seems to be a graphic-card related issue. Therefore, your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @sillyfly If you post your answer, I can mark this question as solved.