# Running the same JavaFx program, it works on one computer but does not work on another

Tags: javafx

I run a javafx simple video game on my destop (windows 10), the sounds and graphics are rendering perfectly. However, I run the same program on my laptop (windows 10), I only got a white screen on the javafx application window and I could hear sounds. When I moved my mouse pointer over the application icon at the task bar, and I saw the graphics in the icon. Please see the snapshot below.
[Only white screen displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZV9a.png)

Comment: Did you try to debug your app on the laptop? Do you have the same installed JREs?

Comment: No, I tried to run the program.

Comment: My desktop: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_151; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.151-b12
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_151-b12
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_CA (nb)

Comment: My laptop: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_161; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.161-b12
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161-b12
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_CA (nb)

Comment: Could be related to a display driver issue/incompatibility. See the discussion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302969/showing-of-javafx-scene-randomly-delayed